# JQuery UI Dialog displaying, not working as dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

### Problem:

The dialog div is displaying without the buttons being pressed, and does not appear as an overlay when I press them. I'm tearing my hair out, so thanks in advance.

### Code:

Includes:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
<script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script src="js/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>
```

Css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.ui.autocomplete.
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.ui.all.
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.ui.theme.
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.ui.dialog.css" />
```

Buttons: `<a class="phoneadder">Stuff</a>`

Scripts:

```
<script>
        $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 300,
            width: 350,
            modal: true
        }
    );
        $( ".phoneadder" ).click(function() {
            $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
            return false;
        });
    </script>
```

Dialog:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new phone">
    <p>All form fields are required.</p>

    <form>
    <fieldset>
        ...some html here
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: are you sure you pasted the css ? or it was just an error here ?

Comment: You have a few missing characters in your stylesheet includes there - I suppose this was just missed by the c&p?

Comment: they vanished when I put them in, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your jQuery code in the `$(document).ready` function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
/// your code here

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Place the initializer in your document.ready, or as shorthand:

```
$(function() { $("#dialog-form").dialog(autoOpen... ); } );
```

Alternatively, make sure your scripts are run after the div is created, so like, in the footer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
  $(function()
  {
    $( ".phoneadder" ).click(function() {
       $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        height: xxx,
        width: xxx,
        modal: true
       });
       return false;
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just put the dialog function in the click event handler?

```
<script>
      $(function()
      {
        $( ".phoneadder" ).click(function() {
           $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
            height: 300,
            width: 350,
            modal: true
           });

           return false;
        });
      });
</script>
```